# Convert string date value to date with current time

Tags: ios, swift, nsformatter

When Convert string formate date value into Date type, the timezone always set to
12:00 AM
How to set to current time of device, when convert  "2021-12-04" to date ?

```
func stringToDateConvertion(date: String, format: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    if let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
        return startDate as Date
    }
    return Date() as Date
}
let dateValue = "2021-12-04"
stringToDateConvertion(date:dateString, format: "YYYY-MM-dd")
```

Result dataString value is

```
 2021-12-04 00:00:00 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 660268800.0
```

How to show current time value "04:37:39 +0000" post fix to date value.

Comment: Unrelated but YYYY is wrong, use yyyy, and casting `Date` to `Date` is pointless

Comment: The current time of the device is not necessarily UTC. Not sure what would be the expected result

Comment: Btw your question doesn't make any sense. What is your goal?

Comment: @vadian I am using yyyy,

Comment: @LeoDabus Goal is date with current time.

Comment: So 10:40 pm UTC

Comment: Brazil -> 2021-12-04 20:40:00 +0000.

Comment: Side notes. If you don't set the date formatter's calendar property it will use the device's calendar. If the user is using the Buddhist calendar the resulting parsed date will be more than 500 years offset

Comment: @kiran no that's wrong 8:40 pm in Brazil should print as `2021-12-04 23:40:00 +0000`. Right now is `2022-01-27 23:41:57 +0000`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241475/discussion-between-kiran-and-leo-dabus).